# Best practice to expand a list (efficiency) in python

Tags: python, list, numpy

I'm working with large data sets. I'm trying to use the NumPy library where I can or python features to process the data sets in an efficient way (e.g. LC).

First I find the relevant indexes:

```
dt_temp_idx = np.where(dt_diff > dt_temp_th)
```

Then I want to create a mask containing for each index a sequence starting from the index to a stop value, I tried:

```
mask_dt_temp = [np.arange(idx, idx+dt_temp_step) for idx in dt_temp_idx]
```

and:

```
  mask_dt_temp = [idxs for idx in dt_temp_idx for idxs in np.arange(idx, idx+dt_temp_step)]
```

but it gives me the exception:

```
The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()
```

Example input:

```
indexes = [0, 100, 1000]
```

Example output with stop values after 10 integers from each indexes:

```
list = [0, 1, ..., 10, 100, 101, ..., 110, 1000, 1001, ..., 1010]
```

1) How can I solve it?
2) Is it the best practice to do it?

Comment: What exactly is the end-goal? How do you plan to use the mask or the range of indices?

Comment: I will use the mask to drop\delete entries from an array.

Comment: What if some sequences overlap? For example for an input of `[0, 5, 100]`, is the expected output list `[0, 1, ..., 15, 100, ..., 110]`?

Comment: I don't think any sequences overlap. On the contrary your suggested expected output may be fine for me.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10062954/valueerror-the-truth-value-of-an-array-with-more-than-one-element-is-ambiguous)

Comment: From the docs for [`numpy.where()`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html): _When only condition is provided, this function is a shorthand for np.asarray(condition).nonzero(). Using nonzero directly should be preferred, as it behaves correctly for subclasses._

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using masks (boolean arrays) are efficient being memory-efficient and performant too. We will make use of [`SciPy's binary-dilation`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.14.0/reference/generated/scipy.ndimage.morphology.binary_dilation.html) to extend the thresholded mask.

Here's a step-by-step setup and solution run-

```
In [42]: # Random data setup
    ...: np.random.seed(0)
    ...: dt_diff = np.random.rand(20)
    ...: dt_temp_th = 0.9

In [43]: # Get mask of threshold crossings
    ...: mask = dt_diff > dt_temp_th

In [44]: mask
Out[44]: 
array([False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False,  True,
       False, False, False, False,  True, False, False, False, False,
       False, False])

In [45]: W = 3 # window size for extension (edit it according to your use-case)

In [46]: from scipy.ndimage.morphology import binary_dilation

In [47]: extm = binary_dilation(mask, np.ones(W, dtype=bool), origin=-(W//2))

In [48]: mask
Out[48]: 
array([False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False,  True,
       False, False, False, False,  True, False, False, False, False,
       False, False])

In [49]: extm
Out[49]: 
array([False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False,  True,
        True,  True, False, False,  True,  True,  True, False, False,
       False, False])
```

Compare `mask` against `extm` to see how the extension takes place.

As, we can see the thresholded `mask` is extended by window-size `W` on the right side, as is the expected output mask `extm`. This can be use to mask out those in the input array : `dt_diff[~extm]` to simulate the deleting/dropping of the elements from the input following [`boolean-indexing`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.indexing.html#boolean-array-indexing) or inversely `dt_diff[extm]` to simulate selecting those.

#### Alternatives with NumPy based functions

**Alternative #1**

```
extm = np.convolve(mask, np.ones(W, dtype=int))[:len(dt_diff)]>0
```

**Alternative #2**

```
idx = np.flatnonzero(mask)
ext_idx = (idx[:,None]+ np.arange(W)).ravel()

ext_mask = np.ones(len(dt_diff), dtype=bool)
ext_mask[ext_idx[ext_idx<len(dt_diff)]] = False
 
# Get filtered o/p
out = dt_diff[ext_mask]
```

Comment: Do you mind helping me writing the same algorithm without using any high-level function? I would like to do it "by hand" at low-level to learn more

Comment: @Luca Do you want to drop or select those from the extended mask?

Comment: I will use the mask to select the entries from an array and drop them. They are considered invalid data to me, I need to detect and remove them

Comment: @Luca Check out just added `Alternative #1`.

Answer (score 0):

`dt_temp_idx` is a numpy array, but still a Python iterable so you can use a good old Python list comprehension:

```
lst = [ i for j in dt_temp_idx for i in range(j, j+11)]
```

If you want to cope with sequence overlaps and make it back a np.array, just do:

```
result = np.array({i for j in dt_temp_idx for i in range(j, j+11)})
```

But beware the use of a set is robust and guarantee no repetition but it could be more expensive that a simple list.